# Unknown database type enum requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySQL57Platform may not support it. Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I created a fresh symfony4 project. Made user Entity using `php bin/console make:user`, then tried to migrate using `php bin/console make:migration`. But then the error pops up

> In AbstractPlatform.php line 434:
>
> Unknown database type enum requested,
>   Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySQL57Platform may not support it.

The strange thing is the User entity doesn't have any `enum` type rather it has a json column of roles, I suppose this is the reason.

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="json")
 */
 private $roles = [];
```

I have seen some answers for the similar question for laravel, But don't know how to fix it in symfony4.

Comment: Could you say your symfony version? As @LeshaZ wrote, no problem for me too, but I use MariaDB!

Comment: i am using symfony 4.2, In my laravel application this problem did not occurred at all

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Couldn't reproduce your issue. But anyway you can set up enum type in doctrine.yaml like

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
       .....
        mapping_types:
            enum: string
```

Here is the corresponding part in the [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/dbal.html#registering-custom-mapping-types-in-the-schematool).

Comment: that did solved the error, but the DB contains just an empty array `[]` instead of `[ROLE_USER]`

Comment: could you share an example how you add that roles

Comment: Thanks, I always forget to add my enum inside doctrine.yaml

Answer (score 5):

To fix this, you can register that type mapping on your migration:

```php
DB::connection()->getDoctrineSchemaManager()->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('enum', 'string');
```

Also, you could register it on `app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php`.

```php
    public function boot() {
        // ...

        DB::connection()
            ->getDoctrineSchemaManager()
            ->getDatabasePlatform()
            ->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('enum', 'string');

        // ....
    }
```

Source: https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/3161#issuecomment-542814085

Comment: This changes the enum column to a varchar. It does not update the enum and retain the enum type.